# Somar valores digitados sem utilizar array

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Elabore um programa que peça ao usuário para digitar 10 valores, some esse resultados e apresente na tela.

Eu só consegui fazer com um *array* de inteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i, soma;
  soma = 0;
  int num[10];
  printf("Digite 10 numeros para somar:\n");
  for(i= 0; i<10; i++) {
    printf("Digite a %d nota: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    soma +=num[i];
  }
  printf("\nSoma = %d : ", soma);

  system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Como faço para somar os 10 valores lidos sem usar array???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O uso do *array* só estava atrapalhando, basta usar uma variável normal ao invés de um *array*, afinal ele não tinha função alguma no algoritmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int soma = 0;
    printf("Digite 10 numeros para somar:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int num;
        printf("Digite a %d nota: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        soma += num;
    }
    printf("\nSoma = %d : ", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gUHrii). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lmdpcfrq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumValues.c).